# How to include file from seperate remote folder in Netbeans (PHP Development)

Tags: php, javascript, netbeans

I have a PHP project setup in Netbeans (v6.8) where all the PHP files are on a remote server and in a single directory. Whenever I save files locally they are updated on the remote server via SFTP.

I now need to edit a remote JavaScript file to add some jQuery logic but the file is located within a different directory on the webserver. How to I add this JavaScript file such that when it is saved or updated it is transferred to it's own location on the server?

When I attempt to create the file locally within NetBeans it saves to the same directory as my PHP files. I would like to be able to continue using NetBeans rather than doing this all manually using an SFTP client and a text editor. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not getting any answers I'll offer a limited suggestion. I use netbeans, but not to automatically upload like you're doing so I may be way off here.

It sounds like you would either need to change your project to have a larger directory structure that would contain everything for this to work like you want it to. Gan you go up a level or two in the directory structure, and add containing folders in your local project to match?

The other option might be to create a second project for the javascript directory, and set that to go were it needs to go. You can create "project groups" in the project view which you can use to link them together. I know this is probably not ideal, but is hopefully easier than doing your uploads manually.